# Android TableLayout in LinearLayout - Remove spaces in between columns and rows

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-tablelayout

I struggle more with UI design in Android than actually making the application, so I was giving something a go:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TableLayout 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TableRow 
            android:id="@+id/rowOne"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" >

            <Button 
                android:id="@+id/BOne"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:text="Button" />

            <Button 
                android:id="@+id/BTwo"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:text="Button" />

            <Button 
                android:id="@+id/BThree"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:text="Button" />

            <Button 
                android:id="@+id/BFour"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:text="Button" />

        </TableRow>

        <TableRow 
            android:id="@+id/rowTwo"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" >

            <Button 
                android:id="@+id/BFive"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:text="Button" />

            <Button 
                android:id="@+id/BSix"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:text="Button" />

            <Button 
                android:id="@+id/BSeven"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:text="Button" />

            <Button 
                android:id="@+id/BEight"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:text="Button" />

        </TableRow>

        <TableRow 
            android:id="@+id/rowThree"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" >

            <Button 
                android:id="@+id/BNine"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:text="Button" />

            <Button 
                android:id="@+id/BTen"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:text="Button" />

            <Button 
                android:id="@+id/BEleven"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:text="Button" />

            <Button 
                android:id="@+id/BTwelve"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:text="Button" />

        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

I have been trying to remove the spaces in between the rows and the columns, I tried giving a negative margin to the rows and the buttons like so:

```
android:layout_marginRight="-20sp"
```

But that is really "fiddly" not very accurate and I don't think it will scale the same for all screens (correct me if I am wrong). I also through giving the rows layout_weight attributes of one would make them cover the entire width of the screen (I know the weight is simply the importance given to the element). Perhaps I need to use stretchColumns? or perhaps there is another tag that might be useful here?

The reson that I have put it in a LinearLayout is because I plan to add other elements and experiment with those as well.

[image: Buttons_screengrab]

Comment: The "space" is caused by Android's default background for `Button`; there is internal padding. You can test it by changing all `android:background` to any color (e.g. `#ccc`) and see how the spaces disappear.

Comment: @AndrewT. Thank you!! I tried doing things with the button padding, but  I didn't know it was caused by the default background!!

Answer (score -1):

Replace your buttons :

```
<Button 
    android:id="@+id/BFour"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button" />
```

with

```
<Button 
    android:id="@+id/BFour"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="Button" />
```